# Service with intents not working. Help needed

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I need help in making my click intents work. I used to have them in my appwidgetprovider, but decided to move them into a service, but I am having trouble getting it to work. Below is the entire code from my intentservice:

```
public class IntentService extends Service {

static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "android.tristan.widget.digiclock.action.UPDATE_2";
private final static IntentFilter sIntentFilter;
public int layoutID = R.layout.clock;
int appWidgetIds = 0;

static {
    sIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(onClickTop, sIntentFilter);
    registerReceiver(onClickBottom, sIntentFilter);
 Log.d("DigiClock IntentService", "IntentService Started.");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(onClickTop);
    unregisterReceiver(onClickBottom);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver onClickTop = new BroadcastReceiver() {

 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {

     if(intent.getAction().equals("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK"))
     {
         PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
         Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

         String clockImpls[][] = {
                 {"HTC Alarm Clock", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
                 {"Standar Alarm Clock", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
                 {"Froyo Nexus Alarm Clock", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"},
                 {"Moto Blur Alarm Clock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",  "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock"}
         };

         boolean foundClockImpl = false;

         for(int i=0; i<clockImpls.length; i++) {
             String vendor = clockImpls[i][0];
             String packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
             String className = clockImpls[i][2];
             try {
                 ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
                 ActivityInfo aInfo = packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                 alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);
                 foundClockImpl = true;
             } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                 Log.d("Error, ", vendor + " does not exist");
             }
         }

         if (foundClockImpl) {
         Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
         vibrator.vibrate(50);
         final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
         views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TopRow, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, DigiClock.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
         AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);
         alarmClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(alarmClockIntent);       
    }
     }
 }
};

     private final BroadcastReceiver onClickBottom = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {

          if(intent.getAction().equals("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK_2"))
          {
              PackageManager calendarManager = context.getPackageManager();
              Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                  String calendarImpls[][] = {
                          {"HTC Calendar", "com.htc.calendar", "com.htc.calendar.LaunchActivity" },
                          {"Standard Calendar", "com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity"},
                          {"Moto Blur Calendar", "com.motorola.blur.calendar",  "com.motorola.blur.calendar.LaunchActivity"}
                  };

              boolean foundCalendarImpl = false;

              for(int i=0; i<calendarImpls.length; i++) {
                  String vendor = calendarImpls[i][0];
                  String packageName = calendarImpls[i][1];
                  String className = calendarImpls[i][2];
                  try {
                      ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
                      ActivityInfo aInfo = calendarManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                      calendarIntent.setComponent(cn);
                      foundCalendarImpl = true;
                  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                      Log.d("Error, ", vendor + " does not exist");
                  }
              }

              if (foundCalendarImpl) {
              Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
              vibrator.vibrate(50);
              final RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
              views2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BottomRow, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, DigiClock.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
              AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views2);
              calendarIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              context.startActivity(calendarIntent);       
         }
          }

};
};
;};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where's the code that sends the `Intent`? I have a feeling that's where your problem is...Also, have you registered this class as a service in the manifest? What about the broadcast receivers?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: I have registered it in the manifest, and I know that it is starting correctly, I can see that in the logcat.

Comment: I am not getting any errors as such, the clicks just don't work. They worked perfectly when they where in the main class.

Comment: What do you mean by "clicks don't work"? What clicks? And what do you consider "working" versus what it's doing?

Comment: I have two onclick intents that each start an activity, but they are not firing when the screen is tapped. The reason I decided to move it into a service is that they stopped working whenever the launcher restarted. I read somewhere that moving them into a service would mend that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that your BroadcastReceivers are private inner classes - they can not be accessed by code outside of your IntentService class.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty probably cause.

Comment: Should I just change it from private to public?